# Find command to list the directory names which consists only of "numbers" (0-9)

Tags: find, directory, filenames

In a particular path, I have a few directories (date as filename), for example:

- if the directory name is like 20180423 it should be listed
- if the directory name is like 20180423-backup or 20180423backup it should not be listed.

Comment: What do you mean by "be listed" in this case? Should `ls` be run on the directory to list its content, or should the directory name/path be listed?

Answer (score 6):

You'd want to use double-negation here:

```
LC_ALL=C find . ! -name '*[!0-9]*' -type d
```

That is list the files of type directory whose name does not contain a non-digit.

Without `LC_ALL=C`, some `find` implementations, including GNU `find` could also list files whose name contains sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters in the current locale (like a `répertoire` encoded in iso8859-1 (`mkdir $'r\xe9pertoire'`) in a locale that uses UTF-8 as charset).

With `zsh`, you can also do:

```
print -rC1 -- **/<->(ND/)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU find:

```
find . -regex '^./[0-9]*$'
```

Adjust the beginning of the regular expression (`^./`) to match the starting path (`.`) if you change it.

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions:

With GNU `find`:

```
find /particular/path -type d -regextype egrep -regex '.*/[0-9]{8}'
```

With standard `find`:

```
find /particular/path -type d -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

These will find any directory in or under `/particular/path` that has a name that consists of eight digits and display their pathnames.

If you by "list" mean that you want to see the contents of those directories, then you may modify the commands above by adding `-exec ls {} ';'`.